# How to combine multiple queue channels with values in Nextflow?

Tags: bioinformatics, pipeline, nextflow

I want to run an analysis multiple times with different variables on the same input from a previous processes on Nextflow:

```
process a {
    output:
    file id, "{id}.out" into a
}

metadata = Channel.fromPath("metadata.tsv")

vars_to_analyze = Channel.from(["var_a", "var_b"])

process b {
    input:
    tuple id, file from a
    file m from metadata
    val var from vars_to_analyze

    output:
    tuple id, path("${id}-${var}.out") into b

    """
    command --var ${var} --metadata ${m} ${file} > ${id}-${var}.out
    """
}
```

Which is the correct way to re-use metadata and file with different values?

Comment: It seems that [combine operator](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/operator.html#combine) should be the way, but cant seem to make it work:

`combined = a.combine(metadata).combine(vars_to_analyze)`

Comment: what's the issue with .combine() ?

Comment: Does not use the same input multiple times.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use a channel for the metadata file, just declare as

```
metadata = file("metadata.tsv")
```